# Highcharts multiple charts refresh on a single click

Tags: javascript, mobile, charts, highcharts, click

I have four charts displayed on a single page. All charts have drill down function. I want to refresh all the charts with the drill down data whenever I click on any chart. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

To add events on a chart use:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    click: function( ) {
       // reset charts
    }
  }
}
```

To reset charts use the same function for all charts which you are already using for a one chart.